# How to change from empty value to a NaN value in my dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, nan

I have been looking for a solution but most people want to change the NaN value to 0.

I have a dataframe with 500 rows called twitter_df that looks like this (showing first 3 rows): The column name is tweets.

```
Tweets
@BongaDlulane Query escalated to media desk.
@BongaDlulane Please send an email to mediades...
#inwithnew #outwithold : ....
```

I want to extract all the hashtag tweets and make separate column so i used code to get to this answer:

```
Tweets                                                hashtags
@BongaDlulane Query escalated to media desk.             []
@BongaDlulane Please send an email to mediades...        []
#inwithnew #outwithold : ....                            [#inwithnew,#outwithold]
```

Now what i want to do is change '[]' values into 'NaN' values.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:
`df.replace([], np.NaN)`